# Android Emulator Not Showing Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, emulation, google-play-services

Ok guys hello I am developing an android app which uses Google Maps. I followed a tutorial on internet and completed it successfully but the emulator is saying app won't work because google play libraries are not on phone.
1. I have imported the google playstore library.
2. I have google api image of android 5.0
following is my code.
This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.taxiapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<permission 
    android:name="com.taxiapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"
    />
<uses-permission android:name="com.taxiapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.taxiapp.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.taxiapp.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.taxiapp.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.taxiapp.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.taxiapp.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature 
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

  <meta-data 
      android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value="AIzaSyAxvr6dSj58P5O4eypi8VkfdqBfoEWYtbE"
      />
  <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
  <!-- "@string/title_activity_home" > -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".QuickBook"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_quick_book" >
    </activity>

 </application>

</manifest>
```

this is my layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.taxiapp.QuickBook" >

  <fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my activity

```
package com.taxiapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

public class QuickBook extends Activity {
GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quick_book);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quick_book, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

![enter image description here][1]

Here is my project explorer showing imported google play library

![enter image description here][2]

I am not able to post snapshot of the emulator but the activity opens and the view is saying "THIS App wont run without google play services, which are missing from your phone"

I am using google maps api 2

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember when I was implementing Google Maps, you can't use it as it doesn't support Google Play Services. I recently found this cool emulator: http://www.genymotion.com/

Maybe take a look at that to see if it helps!

Comment: Thanks For Your Answer but Genymotion is paid do you have any working solution inside eclipse

Comment: Genymotion is not paid. You can use free features aswell. only few features are paid ones.

Comment: Thanks Connor McFadden for your Help. GenyMotion Is Working. But It also Required play services to be installed manually like avd's in sdk. But i have to say that GenyMotion is way superfast than AVD's

Answer (score 0):

for use Google services you need a device or a VM with Google services installed...
The VM created in you ADT do not have any of theses applications, you need install them!

Search for gapps and good luck!